# Maximum words we can enter in table column

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to add more than 4000 latter in sqlserver database table column but not able to as max latter for nvarchar is 4000 only

how can i add more than 4k latter , what data type should i use?

Comment: Have you tried `nvarchar(max)` ?

Comment: yes,but when i try to enter word with textbox i can't , i am only able to add it manually in table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your column to : `nvarchar(max)`

[nvarchar(max)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx)

> Variable-length Unicode string data. n defines the string length and
>   can be a value from 1 through 4,000. **max indicates that the maximum
>   storage size is 2^31-1 bytes (2 GB).** The storage size, in bytes, is
>   two times the actual length of data entered + 2 bytes. The ISO
>   synonyms for nvarchar are national char varying and national character
>   varying.

Comment: thanks , but i am only able to enter words directly to table column means by opening  show table data and than entering ,but when i try to enter words with textbox it enters 4k only,what is reason for that?

Comment: @vikas, there could be multiple issues, See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720021/asp-net-textbox-issue) for related info.

Answer (score 1):

nvarchar(max) would do it, but you'll lose the ability to index etc on that column...

Comment: It would not allow you to create an index on a `nvarchar(4000)` either, or any column that can be bigger than 900 bytes.